# How to keep time information updated on a WiFi Android device, but without GMS, RTC and GPS?

Tags: android, clock, ntp

I am new to Android world and now I am writing an application on an WiFi, Android (without GMS) device, but the device has no RTC and GPS.
Can I still get time information (and continuously updated) in my application?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are time servers that you can access to get the current time, such as [Google Public NTP](https://developers.google.com/time/guides). Although keeping the time updated is typically a core component of the operating system and it shouldn't fall on you to keep track just for your application.